# Fiware - Orion Context Broker subscription expiration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I'm working with Orion context Broker version 1.0.0. I have an active subscription constantly receiving notifications that should be redirected to a cygnus.

My concern is that last thursday this subscription did expire. Theorically, while a subscription keeps sending notifications to it's subscribers, the expiration date is updated. Then, anyone knows why that active subscription did expire?

That's how I do the subscription registrations:

```
(curl 172.21.0.33:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Fiware-Service: xxxx' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /xxxx/xxxx' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d  @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "tmp_reading",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": ".*"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [],
    "reference": "http://172.21.0.23:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": []
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

One temporal solution seems to be to establish a very large duration period. Is that neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Theorically, while a subscription keeps sending notifications to it's subscribers, the expiration date is updated

That's not correct. On the contrary, a subscription is active as long as it hasn't reached its expiration date, which is calculated with current time + duration at subcription creation/updating time ([in NGSIv1](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/duration/index.html)) or directly is the value of the `expires` field ([in NGSIv2](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/)), no matter if notifications are being sent or not.

In addition, note that NGSIv2 allows to create permanent subscriptions (the ones created without specifying the `expires` field).